# Replacing multiple variables in a text substring in excel

Tags: excel, replace, find, match

I am using Excel for Mac 2016.

In column B there are 1.000+ product names, alphanumeric. One part of the product name can be the name of a color.

I now want to separate the color name from the product name and move the color name to column C, replacing it in column B with "" (empty).

In column A I have listed all color names that can appear in the product name.

My problem is to have the list of color names in A to look for as a substring in B. I tried arrays and ranges with SEARCH and FIND but only the first color is matched.
I have tried `=FIND({26,29},B2)` and `=FIND(A1:A10;B2)`

Hope to find help here.

Sample data:

column a: 
black
yellow
red
column b:
first product red
second product black 2018
third product 2017

**edit**
After using the provided formula from below I changed it to get only the color in a  separate field. I am using this:

```
Public Function getColor(rngSource As Range, rngReplace As Range, strDelim As String) 
As String Dim varInput 
Dim rngFound As Range varInput = Split(rngSource.Value, strDelim) 
For i = LBound(varInput) To UBound(varInput) 
Set rngFound = rngReplace.Find(varInput(i)) 
Next i 
getColor = Application.Trim(rngFound) End Function
```

It works fine, but when no color is found in a field I do not get EMPTY but an error. How do I tell the code that empty is also ok as a result?

Comment: Can you post some sample data please?

Comment: added some data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about Mac Environment but this is standard Excel formula which should work.

Setup :

Color Names in Cell          : `A1:A3`

Source data begins from cell : `B1`

Formula for cell `B1` data :

`=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(" "&B1&" "," "&IFERROR(LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(" "&$A$1:$A$3&" "," "&B1&" ",1),$A$1:$A$3),"|")&" "," "))`

Copy down as much as needed.

**Edit**

Just to give an idea, two word replacement formula will look like below:

`=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(" "&B1&" "," "&IFERROR(LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(" "&$A$1:$A$3&" "," "&B1&" ",1),$A$1:$A$3),"|")&" "," ")," "&IFERROR(LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(" "&$A$1:$A$3&" "," "&SUBSTITUTE(" "&B1&" "," "&IFERROR(LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(" "&$A$1:$A$3&" "," "&B1&" ",1),$A$1:$A$3),"|")&" "," ")&" ",1),$A$1:$A$3),"|")&" "," "))`

It will become only unmanageable beyond this point if you intend to have it for three words.

UDF - User Defined Function is written using `VBA`. See below code which you can use as starting point:

```
Public Function ReplaceWords(rngSource As Range, rngReplace As Range, strDelim As String) As String
Dim varInput
Dim rngFound As Range
varInput = Split(rngSource.Value, strDelim)
For i = LBound(varInput) To UBound(varInput)
    Set rngFound = rngReplace.Find(varInput(i))
    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then varInput(i) = ""
Next i
ReplaceWords = Application.Trim(Join(varInput, strDelim))
End Function
```

Comment: works. thanks a lot.
for all german fellas, here's the german excel version of the formula: `=GLÄTTEN(WECHSELN(" "&B1&" ";" "&WENNFEHLER(VERWEIS(2^15;SUCHEN(" "&$A$1:$A$3&" ";" "&B1&" ";1);$A$1:$A$3);"|")&" ";" "))`

Comment: after working with it there still is a problem.
i have several colors that include other colors, like
"anthrazit black white red". It happens that a product name that has "anthrazit black white red" says "anthrazit red" after applying the formula from above. How to solve that?

Comment: @Axel then the approach may need some tweak. If there are only few such cases then SUBSTITUTE could be nested but then formula will become long and unwieldy. Using a UDF would be better.

Comment: what is a UDF? isn't there a way to let the formula match more than one value from the color list?

Comment: got it. thanks. 
I altered the code to get the color found - and it is working unless there is no color found at all. then i get an error. what to do? my code is
    `Public Function getColor(rngSource As Range, rngReplace As Range, strDelim As String) As String
    Dim varInput
    Dim rngFound As Range
    varInput = Split(rngSource.Value, strDelim)
    For i = LBound(varInput) To UBound(varInput)
       Set rngFound = rngReplace.Find(varInput(i))
    Next i
    getColor = Application.Trim(rngFound)
    End Function`

Comment: @Axel I am not able to understand requirement here. You should edit original question, Comments are not for posting big lines of code.